# Centering an img inside li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have many `li`s under `ul` . I have written here my first image which I pass source in javascript dynamically. My image is left aligned, I need it to be centered.

```js
$("#imgemp").attr("src", src);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="imgli">
    <img id="imgemp" border="0" width="90" height="90">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a little unclear what the actual problem is, centering images is simple **unless there is something you haven't mentioned**. A *minimal* demo would be quite helpful showing the issue.

Comment: What do you mean center? Vertically? Horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `li`'s `width` is big enough (more than 90) than `text-align:center` should do it.

```
<li class="imgli" style='width:200px;text-align:center;' > 
  <img id="imgemp" border="0" width="90" height="90"> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

`image` is an inline element so you can use `text-align:center`.

```js
$("#imgemp").attr("src", src);
```

```css
li {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="imgli">
    <img id="imgemp" border="0" width="90" height="90">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already appended `imgli` class to `li`. Why not just use this?

```
.imgli{
    text-align: center;
}
```